# Is this a good way to disable scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable scrolling of the underlying content on my page while a modal is showing. I came across this code to disable page scrolling. (http://jsfiddle.net/77P2e/)

```
var $window = $(window), previousScrollTop = 0, scrollLock = false;

$window.scroll(function(event) {     
    if(scrollLock) {
        $window.scrollTop(previousScrollTop); 
    }

    previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
});

$("#lock").click(function() {
    scrollLock = !scrollLock;
});
```

It seems to work well and cover all possible scroll methods (wheel, middle mouse click, etc). But is there any disadvantage to using this as compared to setting overflow: hidden or some other method?

Comment: The disadvantage here is that disabling scrolling is infuriating to most users.

Comment: There is no good way to disable scrolling.

Comment: WHY do you want to disable scrolling? How are they supposed to see the part that doesn't fit?

Comment: What happens if I disable JS?

Comment: Disabling scrolling is meant to be temporary for when a modal window is open.

Comment: @tumber033: That was useful information to include in the question (so I've edited it in).

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) in combination with `overflow`. This would completely disable all interaction with a given DOM element and will partially limit interacting with its children.

```
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you only want to disable scrolling after the user has performed a certain action, or for any other reason, you can neatly apply this class to your code conditionally.

Because you use jQuery, you can use its `addClass` and `removeClass` functions to toggle this class on and off. You can also use `toggleClass`, depending on preference. I personally prefer to not use it, because the `addClass` and `removeClass` makes me feel more in control.

Comment: neat idea - I also like these alternatives to the OPs code because 1) jQuery not required and 2) "*Since scroll events can fire at a high rate*, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications.": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad way but you can also toggle `overflow:hidden` like below

```
$("#lock").click(function() {
    scrollLock = !scrollLock;
    document.body.classList[scrollLock ? "add" : "remove"]("noScroll")
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77P2e/26/) here.

**Explanation:**

I consider setting `overflow: hidden` better way because of it's simplicity and in some browsers setting scroll positions manually could be jumpy. For example in Mac due to its scrolling effects.

Comment: The question says that he knows about this. I suppose your answer should explain why this is better (if it is).

Comment: Tested only in Chrome and Safari as I use Mac. Don't know about behaviour of Internet god IE.

Comment: @Barmar Added why I feel this is better approach over setting scroll position manually.

Comment: Maybe better to use jQuery `toggleClass`, for better compatbility, since he's already using jQuery.